# gemfire local region creation

Tags: xml, spring, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have my cache.xml as below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire-1.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<cache:annotation-driven />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test-cache.properties"
    system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" />

<util:properties id="gemfireProperties">
    <prop key="mcast-port">0</prop>
    <prop key="log-level">info</prop>
    <prop key="license-data-management">${license-data-management}</prop>
</util:properties>

<gfe:cache properties-ref="gemfireProperties" id="gemfireCache" />


<gfe:local-region id="pet-region">
    <gfe:cache-listener>
        <bean
            class="com.mycompany.cache.TestLoggingCacheListener" />
    </gfe:cache-listener>
</gfe:local-region>
```

I see an exception as below

> schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document
>   'http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire-1.2.xsd',
>   because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
>   read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
>
> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for element 'gfe:cache'.

I tried changing to different versions of xsd's as below but had no luck I still see the issue.

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd

and

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire-1.1.xsd

and

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire-1.2.xsd

After all the above tries, when I changed to 1.1 version, I see it throws another issue now

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for element 'gfe:local-region'.

can anyone help me how can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this. It was with the spring version which needs to be changed to 3.1.1 and gemfire with 6.6.2. I was basically a compatibility issue.